# How to solve the equation $\log_5x+\log(x+1)=\frac{\log12}{1-\log2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, roots

How can one solve the equation: $$\log_5x+\log(x+1)=\frac{\log12}{1-\log2}$$

Comment: what are the base used for the remaining $\log$? is it base $10$?

Comment: yes, log is common logarithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming natural logarithms, consider the function
$$f(x)=\frac{\log (x)}{\log (5)}+\log (x+1)-\frac{\log (12)}{1-\log (2)}$$ The derivative $$f'(x)=\frac{1}{x \log (5)}+\frac{1}{x+1}$$ is always positive since $x>0$ (because of the first logarithm). So, only one root for the equation.

There is no way to get an analytical solution and numerical methods will be required. In order to start properly, notice that you can bound
$$\frac{\log (x)}{\log (5)}+\log (x)<\frac{\log (x)}{\log (5)}+\log (x+1)<\frac{\log (x+1)}{\log (5)}+\log (x+1)$$ and now solve 
$$\frac{\log (x)}{\log (5)}+\log (x)=\frac{\log (12)}{1-\log (2)}\to x_1\approx 147.625$$ 
$$\frac{\log (x+1)}{\log (5)}+\log (x+1)=\frac{\log (12)}{1-\log (2)}\to x_2\approx 146.625$$ So, the solution is such that $x_2 < x < x_1$ which is a quite narrow range.

Now, you can safely start Newton method using for example $x_0=\frac{x_1+x_2}2$ and the iterates would be 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\ 
  0 & 147.12500000000000000 \\
 1 & 147.00891502331094510 \\
 2 & 147.00896061800955855 \\
 3 & 147.00896061801659974
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is the solution for twenty significant figures.

Comment: thanks for your attentions

Comment: @somkiat_t. You are very welcome ! Did you pick all the steps ?